# Referenced array object doesn't return class variable when iterating - terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, terminate

So I'm trying to iterate through a dynamic array(required) of a class "Candidate" which has the getter "getVotes()" in order to get the votes to tally up with "totalVotes()" to return the total number of votes and to return the % of the total votes a candidate gets.

However, whenever the program executes, it will output the total votes, the candidates and their votes correctly, but won't calculate the % of total votes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiSWu.jpg

It also throws the exception: 
"Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' 
   what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

and at times the total votes printed out is just a garbage number, which might be the program adding addresses?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKBsK.jpg

I've tried putting a cout to see if number are being added in the "totalVotes" function, but nothing prints out.

I know "getVotes()" works because it still lists the correct number of votes.

```
class Candidate
{
    int Votes;
//...
    Candidate(string, int);
//...
    int getVotes() {return Votes;}
    void setVotes(int votes){Votes = votes;}
};
```

```
//return total votes 
int totalVotes(Candidate *x) 
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(x); i++)
    {
        total = total + x[i].getVotes();
    }
    return total;
}
```

```
//main
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int noc;
    int voteTotal;
    cout << "Declare the number of candidates: ";
    cin >> noc;
    Candidate* candidates = new Candidate[noc+1];

    //get list of candidates
    for(int i = 0; i<noc; i++)
    {
        string name;
        int votes;
        cout << "Name for candidate " << i+1 << "?: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "How many votes did they get?: ";
        cin >> votes;
        candidates[i].setName(name);
        candidates[i].setVotes(votes);
    }

    //get total votes from candidates
    voteTotal = totalVotes(candidates); 
    cout << "Total Votes: " << voteTotal << endl;

    cout << setw(20) << "Candidate" <<
            setw(20) << "Votes Received" <<
            setw(20) << "% of Total Votes" << '\n';

    //return list of candidates (Why does this work and not "totalVotes()"?)
    for(int i = 0; i<(int)sizeof(candidates)-1; i++) 
    {
        cout << setw(20) << candidates[i].getName() <<
                setw(20) << candidates[i].getVotes() <<
                setw(20) << setprecision(2) << (candidates[i].getVotes()/voteTotal)*100 << "%\n";
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

So program crashes immediately after the candidates are listed, along with an empty row being printed out.

I'm not sure.

Comment: You want to be very careful about using sizeof() to determine array size. In your totalVotes() function, you call sizeof() on a Candidate * pointer. In this case, sizeof returns the size, in bytes, of a pointer.

Comment: Go for a `std::vector` of `Candidate` and most of your issues will be resolved.

Comment: Using sizeof() to check array length works when you've statically declared an array, because its value is computed at compile time. However, you will need to divide the result by the size of a single element, otherwise you will have the wrong length.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(x); i++)` -- The `x` is a pointer.  You are not going to get the length of an array by taking the `sizeof` a pointer.  The same thing here: `for(int i = 0; i<(int)sizeof(candidates)-1; i++) ` -- This is wrong for the same reason.  Who is teaching or what book / website is telling you that using `sizeof` gives you the number of entries?  All `sizeof` does is give you the number of bytes the type takes up, not anything like the number of entries allocated by `new[]`.

Comment: Simply put, the only information in that program that tells you the number of entries is the variable `noc`.  Nothing else has this information, so you need to save that somewhere, make it a member variable of your class, etc.

Comment: So now I'm using 


`int sizeOf(const Candidate *x)
{
    return((int)sizeof(x)/(int)sizeof(x[0]));
}`


but the size returns as 0?

Also @PaulMcKenzie, how should I store the variable noc?

thanks!

Comment: I already mentioned that the only part of your code that knows the number of entries is `noc`.  No "sizeof" tricks are going to help.  The `sizeof` is the totally wrong thing to do -- again `x` is a `Candidate *` -- a pointer.   Bottom line is this -- `new[]` does not "remember" the number of entries, a pointer does not know how big the buffer it is pointing to.   That responsibility of knowing how many entries are `new[]`-ed is all on your shoulders, and you know the number of entries via the `noc` variable.

Comment: sizeof() is evaluated at compile time. During runtime, it is basically just a constant, as  if you wrote 4,5,10 or some other number there instead of the sizeof(), but it's the compiler that writes the number there. If you don't know the size of the array at compile time, how would sizeof know the size of the array? This is the main disadvantage of C style arrays, that they do not carry their size with them and you need to manually pass the size of the array as separate value to functions working with the array when they are allocated dynamically.